# Cannot create or update posts using php v3 library on a previously invitation-only blog

Tags: php, blogger, google-api-php-client

I use the Blogger library for php,I can not edit an existing post. 
This works fine on a publicly accessible blog where the authenticated user is an "author". 
However, on a blog which was originally set to "invitation-only", with 
exactly the same user having administrator privileges, neither 
programmatic creation nor update works. I can read the post.

The error message was:

> (403) We're sorry, but you don't have permission to access this resource.'
>
> #0 ./GoogleClientApi/src/io/Google_REST.php(36): 
>   Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
>
> #1 ./GoogleClientApi/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(186): 
>   Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
>
> #2 ./GoogleClientApi/src/contrib/Google_BloggerService.php(372): 
>   Google_ServiceResource->__call('update', Array)
>
> #3 main.php(137): 
>   Google_PostsServiceResource->update('854693594998780...', '218373723174711...', Object(Google_Post))
>
> #4 main.php(166): publi in ./GoogleClientApi/src/io/Google_REST.php on line 67

in brief:

```
Array
(
[error] => Array

    (
        [errors] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [domain] => global
                        [reason] => forbidden
                        [message] => We're sorry, but you don't have permission to access this resource.
                    )

            )

        [code] => 403
        [message] => We're sorry, but you don't have permission to access this resource.
    )
```

)

the code is:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
```

**Setting the client object**

```
$blogger = new Google_BloggerService($client);
```

**request code**

```
$code = $_GET['code']; // i got it
$client->authenticate($code);
```

//end the setup

```
/* any function call this, */
$data = $blogger->posts->update($blogId, $postId, $post);
```

this make a PUT request with some data, i think this is not important, if so, i ll put the request later

my code is like this:
http://gayanonline.blogspot.com.ar/2013/03/google-api-v3-with-php-using-blogger.html

For the initiation part.

thanks, and sorry for my english.
Emanuel